# Show window modal to window in other thread

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-4.0

I have in my application the standard UI-Thread and additional a second UI-Thread. Now, I create and show a Window in the second UI-Thread. After this, I should create and show a Dialog in the standard UI-Thread but it should be modal to the window, which was created and shown in the second UI-Thread. The reason is, that I have to create this Dialog in the standard UI-Thread, that this Dialog uses a Control which is not ThreadSafe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just be able to set `Owner` property of the window:

```
newWindow.Owner = parentWindowFromOtherThread;
```

Comment: I'm not; the OP specified it as a requirement

Comment: I'm sorry, I have made mistake when place comment here, it is a comment to question.